# What species have had their genomes sequenced/are being sequenced?

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing, genomes, human-genome

The human genome project released it's first complete genome nearly ten years ago. Since then many species have also been sequenced.

I am trying to find a list of completed (and possibly ongoing/initiated) projects sequencing other species along with some very basic summary data such as number of genes (divided amongst the sex chromosomes and autosomes), length of DNA, number of chromosomes etc.

This is for a presentation I am giving at a conference and would make a nice addition to my talk.

Comment: "ongoing/initiated" is data you just cannot collect. There are more sequencing projects ongoing at some university which have not been publicly mentioned (and often won't before they are finished) than I would be willing to count. I am involved in at least 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GOLD database (Genomes Online DB)](http://www.genomesonline.org/) contains data on the sequencing status, and also some stats (number of chromosomes, genome size) -- but this extra data is not available for all species.

Answer (score 3):

There are several lists on Wikipedia, for example for [plants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequenced_plant_genomes), [bacteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequenced_bacterial_genomes) and [eucaryotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequenced_eukaryotic_genomes).

Answer (score 1):

The [Genome 10K project](https://genome10k.soe.ucsc.edu/), in their words "aims to assemble a genomic zoo—a collection of DNA sequences representing the genomes of 10,000 vertebrate species, approximately one for every vertebrate genus.". [Here is their species list](https://genome10k.soe.ucsc.edu/species).

Answer (score 1):

At NCBI, you can find a table with [genome Information per organism](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/browse/).

For each organism, you can find the Kingdom, group and subgroup it belongs to, the size in Megabases, the number of chromosomes, organelles and plasmids (if present) and the number of assemblies.